# Powershell: Getting 0 from Read-Host and Substring comparison with 0 returns false

Tags: powershell

Im doing a `-eq` comparison by having a user enter a 3 digit number. If the first number is equal two 0, I need to set a variable to a value. The issue is, 0 is not equaling 0 and returning false.

> If $myNumber = 0

This returns false

```
$myNumber = Read-Host "Enter Number"
$firstNum = $myNumber.Substring(0,1)
if ($firstNum -eq '0') {write-host "True"} else {write-host "False"}
```

I tried this and still returns false

```
$myNumber = Read-Host "Enter Number"
$firstNum = $myNumber.Substring(0,1)
if ([int]$firstNum -eq [int]'0') {write-host "True"} else {write-host "False"}
```

I tried varying combinations but I can never get it to return true, BUT it works with any other number.

> If $myNumber = 7

This returns true

```
$myNumber = Read-Host "Enter Number"
$firstNum = $myNumber.Substring(0,1)
if ($firstNum -eq '7') {write-host "True"} else {write-host "False"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works as expected on my machine. But there are some uncertainties: What do you want to compare: numbers, characters or strings? Your values you want to compare against are definitely characters (`'x'`). But it is not 100% clear what type `$firstNum` has. As a substring, it should be a string. But as it is a string of length 1, it could also be a character. And it could also be interpreted as a number. Try `$firstNum.GetType()` after you read the substring. It is a string on my side. If it is not on yours, make sure to cast it like `[string]$firstNum = $myNumber.Substring(0,1)`.

Comment: $mynumber = 0 is an assignment.

Comment: It works for me.  What are you literally typing at the read-host prompt?  Try to print out what $firstnum is.

Comment: `$myNumber = 0` would always be false.

Comment: Or if you literally set `$myNumber = 0`, the substring method would fail for integers, and $firstnum would be $null, not '0'.

Comment: To answer everyone question. Ideally the number entered by the user should be an integer since I am doing some math on it after the number is entered. I am not actually assigning the `$myNumber = 0` this was to show as an example of what the value after being entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is the difference between the number 7 and the character string '007'.  Try these exercises.

```
$s = '007'
if ($s[0] -eq '0') {'007 Starts with zero'} else {'007 Starts with non zero'}

$x = '707'
if ($x[0] -eq '0') {'707 Starts with zero'} else {'707 Starts with non zero'}

$n = 7
if ($n[0] -eq '0') {' 7 Starts with zero'} else {'7 Starts with non zero'}
```

Next, you need to read from the host without converting numeric input to a number.  Try this:

```
[string]$s = Read-Host 'Input 3 digits'
"Your input was $s"
if ($s[0] -eq '0') {'Input starts with zero'} else {'Input starts with non zero'}
```

Try inputting 707, then try inputting 007.

Comment: This works to some extent but when I try to set `$myNumber = $s[0]` it returns false no matter how I put the IF statement.